# Realtime status of hardware connected to server using ExpressJS

Tags: node.js, express, server, client-server, hardware

I have a linux machine on which I want to run a local server using ExpressJS. To that machine a couple of instruments are connected via a USB-to-RS485-adapter which can be controlled and updated using NodeJS. What I want to do is display a live status feed of the instruments (mostly pressure gauges) and update some graphs that display the current pressure that the gauges are measuring. I already have a Server that runs ExpressJS, but I don't know how to make the Node code for controlling the hardware influence the status. Do I have to run the node code server side and then send data to the client with socket.io or is there some easier way. I'm completely new to expressJS and webapps, so it would be nice if you could point me in the right direction and explain to me how that works.

Comment: As of the real time part, socket.io will be better than express, so you should end up serving the webpage with express, and the status with socket.io. As of retrieving the data, how do you get it in the first place? A simple set up would be to retrieve it and push event with the new values on socket.io

Comment: So the retrieval of the data works in a way that let's me trigger an event every time I get a new value of the pressure. I'm playing around with socket.io right now and I think I will do it like you suggested.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Express is a framework to make a web server, while very good for what it does, real time is not what it does.

Instead, socket.io is really good at real time transmissions.

What you should do is serve your "status" page with Express, page that connect to socket.io and subscribe for your "data" event.

Then all you have to do is, when you retrieve the data, send event with socket.io to make the data appear in near real-time on the web page.